# What is the minimum age at which you could work for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, legal, terms-of-service, company, age

Just asking for a friend who's two years younger than I am.

Comment: In what capacity?

Comment: why is this being downvoted so heavily?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Legally*? I suppose 14, [assuming Stack Exchange isn't hiring you to work on a farm](https://labor.ny.gov/workerprotection/laborstandards/workprot/lschlhrs.shtm).

Realistically, I suspect they'd *like* employees to be adults to simplify the legal proceedings. Still, if you're a C# wizard and worth the extra hassle... why not?

Comment: They do hire a few interns :D I suppose that could count as "working"?

Comment: Is a server farm a farm?